# What are the betting rounds for badugi?

Tags: rules, poker-stars

The rules for Pokerstars Badugi doesn't state what bets are available.
https://www.pokerstars.uk/poker/games/badugi/

Assuming it's BTN/SB versus BB and both decide to keep raising and calling if raise is not an option, how would the betting go? Assuming large enough stacks also. Observing a few games I believe it would roughly go like

**1st betting round**

BTN posts 0.5BB, BB posts 1BB

BTN raise to 2BB (putting 1.5BB in, +1.5BB), pot 3BB

BB raise to 3BB (+2BB), pot 5BB

BTN raises to 4BB (+2BB), pot 7BB

BB can't raise, calls (+1BB), pot 8BB

**1st draw**

**2nd betting round**

BB +1BB, BTN +2BB, BB +2BB, BTN +1BB (call) pot 14BB

**2nd draw**

**3rd betting round**

BB +2BB, BTN +4BB, BB +4BB, BTN +2BB (call) pot 26BB

**3rd draw**

**4rd betting round**

BB +2BB, BTN +4BB, BB +4BB, BTN +2BB (call) pot 38BB

**Showdown**

Answer (score 1):

Same as any triple draw poker game (Badugi typically plays with a triple draw). Get hole cards, round of betting from under the gun. Draw, bet a second round. Draw than bet a third round. Draw then bet a fourth round. Same as hold-em. You can play it triple draw, single draw, limit or no limit. Badugi is just a four card draw game with a different way of ranking hands. Nothing about the betting is any different then a five card draw game.

Comment: I would say "same as other triple-draw games". Standard draw poker has only one draw and thus only two betting rounds.

Comment: I will say that.